# Symbolic link pointing to network path instead of a local path

Tags: network-shares, symbolic-link, file-sharing, shared-folders, network-location

I am trying to setup a way to have a network file path mount as if it's on my local drive in Windows.
ex: "\10.0.0.205\Files" shows up as "C:\Volumes\Files".

I have tried mklink in command line and creating a symbolic link in power shell.  Both work great when navigating in windows explorer, but when I try to navigate to the location through an application, such as anything from Adobe or Autodesk, it will automatically change the file path to the network location on \10.0.0.205 instead of the local C:\ location.

Every application I've tried seems to do this, does anyone know if there is there a way around this or another solution that might work better?